# Origins of the base names?

Tags: planetside-2

There are a lot of bases in Planetside, and while most of them are pretty self explanatory (Quartz Ridge Camp, Abandoned Mineshaft, etc) the major ones are all named things like Zurvan Amp Station and so forth. A few of the Esamir names are familiar to me (Ymir, Freyr) but a lot of them I don't recognize (Elli, Mani, Eisa, Nott, etc). This question has nothing to do with gameplay, but I'm still very curious to know where these names came from.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Indar**

- Dahaka: [Persian Mythology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_mythology#Good_and_Evil)/[Zoroastrianism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoroastrianism), an evil figure also called [Zahhak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zahhak)
- Saurva: Also from Zoroastrianism, [one of the arch-demons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daeva#In_Zoroastrian_tradition)
- Mao: [Persian moon god](http://www.pantheon.org/articles/m/mao.html)
- Hvar: [Persian sun god](http://www.pantheon.org/articles/h/hvar.html)
- Allatum: Iranian mythology, [goddess of the underworld](http://www.pantheon.org/articles/a/allatum.html)
- Zurvan: Also related to Zoroastrianism or rather it's branch [Zurvanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zurvanism)
- Rashnu: Again Zoroastrianism, [a divine being](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashnu)
- Tawrich: Like Saurva [another arch-demon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daeva#In_Zoroastrian_tradition) in Zoroastrianism
- Peris: Most likely related to [Peri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peri) in the persian mythology

Theme appears to be persian mythology and Zoroastrianism, possibly due to the generally desert/barren landscape of Indar.

**Esamir**

- Mani: [Moon in norse mythology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1ni)
- Freyr: [A norse god](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freyr)
- Andvari: [A dwarf in norse mythology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andvari)
- Eisa: [A giant in norse mythology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fornj%C3%B3t)
- Nott: [Personification of night in norse mythology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%B3tt)
- Elli: [Personification of old age in norse mythology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elli)
- Ymir: [Again norse mythology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ymir), ancestor of all [jötnar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B6tnar)

Theme here obviously the norse mythology due to the landscape covered in ice and snow.

**Amerish**

- Ikanam: [Chinook mythology](http://www.mythologydictionary.com/ikanam-mythology.html)
- Kwahtee: [Native american trickster god](http://www.mythologydictionary.com/kivati-mythology.html)
- Sungrey: [Native american mythology](http://www.pantheon.org/articles/s/sungrey.html)
- Mekala: [Terrifying female spirit](http://www.pantheon.org/articles/m/mekala.html) in native american mythology
- Heyoka: [A way to live in native american mythology](http://www.pantheon.org/articles/h/heyoka.html)
- Onatha: [The Iroquois spirit of wheat and of harvest.](http://www.pantheon.org/articles/o/onatha.html)
- Wokuk: [A huge and beautiful mythical bird with bright red eyes in Wintun mythology](http://www.pantheon.org/articles/w/wokuk.html)
- Tumas: [Man with Crow Wings tied to.](http://www.pantheon.org/articles/t/tumas.html)
- Xelas: [The transformer-culture-hero of the Lummi Indians of the Puget Sound region.](http://www.pantheon.org/articles/x/xelas.html)

Theme is obviously native american mythology.

I tried to find sources for the continent names themselves but couldn't find anything specific. If someone can help out there and give some reference in the comment, i'll edit it in.

Answer (score 0):

Those names are all taken from old nordic mythology, specifically the ones you listed are those of giants (I haven't played the game yet, so there might be other sources as well).

[This page contains several lists, sorting them by Alphabet or category.](http://runenkunde.de/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=329&Itemid=344) (The page is in German, but tools like Google Translate should help.)

Answer (score -1):

Dahaka may come from Zahak (Dhahak), which is mentioned in the "Shahnameh/ Epic book of kings" from approx. 1100 A.D written by Persian poet Ferdowsi. It refers to an Arab invader during pre-Islamic times, possible Sassanian era.